# OpenID, Google, and pass-through variables?

Tags: openid, lightopenid

I am new to OpenID, and I am using LightOpenID to provide authentication against Google accounts.  Is it possible to perform an authentication that doesn't involve a header redirection or that can pass through any GET and POST variables that exist within the original HTTP request?

Any variables in the original HTTP request get lost when the header redirection takes place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set GET parameters in your `$openid->return_to`.

For example, if you do:

```
$openid->return_to .= '?a=5&b=23'
```

You get `$_GET['a'] == 5`, and `$_GET['b'] == 23` in the request after authentication.

There is no way to set POST parameters this way, or to avoid redirections.